# Where do those nulls come from?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I have seen discussions of unwanted nulls in the output in the context of building lists with conditions on the elements, but that is not involved here. I would like to know where the nulls come from and how to avoid generating them.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

localGroup =
  AstronomicalData["LocalGroup"];

properties = {
   "AlphanumericName",
   "StandardName",
   "AlternateStandardNames",
   "NGCNumber",
   "ApparentMagnitude",
   "Constellation",
   "Declination",
   "RightAscension",
   "DistanceLightYears",
   "GalaxyType",
   "HubbleType",
   "RadialVelocity",
   "Redshift"
   };

lgTable = {#, Table[
      {
       properties[[n]],
       AstronomicalData[#, properties[[n]]]
       },
      {n, 1, Length[properties]}
      ]
     } & /@ localGroup;


displayTable[record_] := Module[{},
  Print[
     #[[1]] <> ": ", #[[2]]
     ] & /@ record[[2]];
  Print["\n"]
  ]

(* display two records for illustration *)

displayTable[#] & /@ lgTable[[1 ;; 2]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `Scan` and `Map` in the documentation, `Scan[Print, {1, 2, 3}]` returns nothing while `Map[Print,{1,2,3}]` returns three `Null`

Just change the last line to:

```
Scan[displayTable, lgTable[[1 ;; 2]]]
```

Comment: A nice bit of magic. Scan has somehow entirely escaped my notice. I am still hoping to find out what generates the nulls.

Comment: @GaryPalmer `Print` is returning `Null` try `x=Print["hello"]` you'll see `FullForm[x]` is `Null`. Or simply `FullForm@Print@1`